# How to integrate this?

Tags: calculus, integration

$$\int{x\sec^2x\,dx}$$

The solution is unclear to me.  I see

$u=x$

$du=dx$

and

$dv=\sec^2x$

$v=\tan x$

I know how to integrate with u-substitution, but, am not sure how to put this all together.

Is there some method I am overlooking?

Comment: Keep in mind the degree of the $x$ multiplier is going to be the number of times you integrate by parts, as shown in the answer below. Future problems will require you to integrate by parts a couple or so times

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use integration by parts:  $$I = uv - \int v\,du\tag{template for IBP}$$

You've done almost all of the work that needs to be done, correctly choosing $u, dv$, and finding $dx$ and $v$.

Putting this altogether, using the above "template", we get:

$$ \int{x\,\sec^2(x)\,dx} \quad = \quad x\tan x \,dx  \;\; - \;\;\int \tan x\,dx$$

Comment: Ok, this is a method I have not yet come across.  I will look up "integration by parts"  Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome, Jack!